# Elasticsearch query from multiple indexes with paination per index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query running over multiple indexes. I want to have pagination per index.
I don't want to lose results just because one index has more results than the other.

```
GET /research-one,research-two/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "urls.value": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "urls.value", 
            "query": "https://stackexchange.com/*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0
}
```

Let's say that in this case, `research-one` has 10000 results and `research-two` has 2 results.
I don't know head which one has more results.
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you simply execute it as two separate searches i.e. one per index?

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant I can, but I think this is a faster method. (also much fewer requests overhead if you have 30 indexes like myself)

Comment: You can probably use [multi search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) to combine multiple searches as a single request.

Comment: Multi search is also what I would recommend in this case

Comment: You could do a term aggregation on _index and a top_hits and paginate on it, but i don't think it will be faster.